# ``Null value stopping rows from displaying

Tags: python, mongodb

I want so show all the students in a database based on an address the user enters. Some have qualifications, some have not.  Regardless of this I would still like to show their details but I am having a difficulty working around the students who have no quailifications.

The below code throws up an error where they have no qualifications but is working fine where they have qualifications.

`KeyError`: `'qualifications'`

How can I work around this?

```
def call_query(address):
    with MongoClient() as client:
        db = client.get_database("test")
        coll = db.get_collection("docs")
        for col in coll.find({"details.address": { "$regex":address}}):
          print (col["_id"] , ":",  col["details"]["name"],":",  col["details"]["age"], col["qualifications"], )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to work it around is to use a try except in your code :

```
def call_query(address):
    with MongoClient() as client:
        db = client.get_database("test")
        coll = db.get_collection("docs")
        for col in coll.find({"details.address": { "$regex":address}}):
          try:
              print (col["_id"] , ":",  col["details"]["name"],":",  col["details"] 
              ["age"], col["qualifications"], )
          except KeyError:
              print (col["_id"] , ":",  col["details"]["name"],":",  col["details"] 
              ["age"], "No qualification", )
```

If the exception is raised because of a None value then it will print "No qualification" for the student

Comment: That works perfectly.  I would have never thought of that.  Thank you.

Comment: Perfect don't forget to mark the question as resolved!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, a dictionary object has a `get` method that allows to set a default value in case the requested key is not found. So, you can simple `col.get("qualifications", "")` which returns empty string if there is no "qualifications" key.

Full code:

```
def call_query(address):
    with MongoClient() as client:
        db = client.get_database("test")
        coll = db.get_collection("docs")
        for col in coll.find({"details.address": { "$regex":address}}):
          print (
              col["_id"] , ":",
              col["details"]["name"],
              ":",
              col["details"]["age"],
              col.get("qualifications", ""), 
          )
```